# Asio does not catch reply from remote system

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost-asio

I'm writing a client that is supposed to listen to a domain socket. I open a synchronous connection, do a synchronous write and I know the server sends a valid response because I'm using socat to [eavesdrop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169228/how-does-moving-a-unix-domain-socket-enable-socat-to-monitor-traffic) on the socket.

Except my `asio::read()` is called but never returns any data. The buffer I pass to it is always empty. Here is my code:

```
void operator>>(const vector<unsigned char> input, Socket &socket) {
      const size_t size = input.size();
      const size_t bytes = asio::write(socket.connection_socket, asio::buffer(input, size));
      if (bytes != size) {
        const std::error_code ec;
        throw std::system_error(ec, fmt::format("Tried to send {0} bytes but sent {1} instead.", size, bytes));
      }
      string buffer;
      asio::read(socket.connection_socket, asio::buffer(buffer));
      std::cerr << buffer << std::endl;
    }
```

These are the properties I use to connect to the socket:

```
io_service run_loop;
stream_protocol::socket connection_socket;
datagram_protocol::endpoint domain_socket_ep;
```

`Socket` is a simple class that wraps all the Asio code, where the operator overload above is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asio::read` function will read **at most** `asio::buffer_size(asio::buffer(buffer))` bytes. In you case `buffer` is empty so it'll read at most zero bytes.

Asio will never resize the buffers you pass into it and thus you need to resize the `buffer` to the maximum size you expect to receive.

Further, the `asio::read` function may actually read less bytes then the size of the input buffer. The actual size it read is returned from that function. Thus if you want to read/write exactly the number of bytes that can fit into the buffer you need to do something like this:

```
void read_to_buffer(asio::ip::tcp::socket& s, asio::buffer buffer) {
    size_t read = 0;
    size_t n = asio::buffer_size(buffer);
    while (read < n) {
        read += asio::read(s, buffer + read));
    }
}

void write_from_buffer(asio::ip::tcp::socket& s, asio::buffer buffer) {
    size_t written = 0;
    size_t n = asio::buffer_size(buffer);
    while (written < n) {
        written += asio::write(s, buffer + written));
    }
}

void operator>>(const vector<unsigned char> input, Socket &socket) {
      // TODO: convert between host and network byte order
      auto& s = socket.connection_socket;
      {
        const uint32_t size = input.size();
        write_from_buffer(s, asio::buffer(&size, sizeof(size));
        write_from_buffer(s, asio::buffer(input));
      }
      {
        uint32_t size = 0;
        read_to_buffer(s, asio::buffer(&size, sizeof(size)));
        string payload(size, 'x');
        read_to_buffer(s, asio::buffer(payload));
        std::cerr << payload << std::endl;
      }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Writing to the socket is fine, asio just doesn't read from it. Why do you need to write and read twice? Also, isn't read_to_buffer() doing the same as asio::read_some?

Comment: "_asio just doesn't read from it_" by passing a string of size zero to the asio::read function you're telling asio to read zero bytes. TCP sockets don't know how many bytes you've sent. "_ same as asio::read_some_", sorry I don't see `asio::read_some` function listed in the [API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html), which one do you mean?

Comment: I meant socket.read_some(): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html

Comment: Ah, all right, the difference is that `read_some` **may** read less than the size of the buffer you're passing into it. On the other hand `read_to_buffer` repeatedly reads from the socket until the full buffer is read.

Comment: And why did you add two writes and two reads? are they examples or are they necessary for a simple read to work?

Comment: The first write is important because it tells the receiver how how many bytes should the receiver receive into the payload buffer. The the first `read_to_buffer` reads this `size`, then the next line creates the `payload` buffer of size `size` and the next `read_to_buffer` reads exactly `size` bytes into `payload`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126137/discussion-between-peter-jankuliak-and-ruipacheco).

Comment: I found that socket has an available() method that returns the number of bytes available for reading. That makes everything much easier.